# pivot_longer with multiple time variables on columns

Tags: r, tidyr

I am trying to transform a wide dataset into long format for further analysis using Linear-Mixed-Effects Models (LME), which requires such format. I want to use the **pivot_longer function from "tidyr" in R.**

My dataset columns start with general data and continue with the measured variables. It looks as following:

```
|"SubjectID"|Gender|Age|...|"var1_t1"|"var1_t2"|...|"var1_t10"|...|"varN_t1"|"varN_t2"|...|"varN_t10"|
```

That is, the dataset contains several variables (var1,...var10), done in multiple timepoints (t1,...tN). I want to transform this dataset into long format with the "pivot_long" function but I am not sure how to. The desired format would like like this:

```
|"SubjectID"||Gender|Age|...|TimePoint|"var1"|"var2"|...|"varN"|
```

Could you please give me a hint? I see input parameters for defining the prefix of the column names, but not the suffixes.

For now I only transformed the variable names of my dataset from Month names to timepoint tags, for (I hope) easier usage in pivot_longer.

```
library(stringr)
timePoints<-c("NovStart"="T1","Dec"="T2","Jan"="T3","Feb"="T4","March"="T5","Mar" = "T5","April"="T6","May"="T7","June"="T8","July"="T9","Aug"="T10","Sept"="T11","Oct"="T12","Nov_End"="T12","NovEnd"="T12")
#Need to rename the month suffixes to later apply the pivot_longer function.
names(dataframe)<-str_replace_all(names(dataframe),timePoints)
print(names(dataframe))
```

Comment: Could you please send a minimal part of your `dataframe`? It is important to always make your question reproducible

Comment: run the command ```dput(data frame)``` , or whatever the name of your data frame is, and paste the answer here (or in your question directly).  This is easy, and once you send it, I can help you answer your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve your desired result using the special `".value"` in the `names_to` argument of `pivot_longer`.

Using some fake example data:

```r
library(tidyr)

dat <- data.frame(
  SubjectID = c(1, 2),
  Gender = c("M", "F"),
  Age = c(20, 30),
  var1_t1 = 1:2,
  var1_t2 = 3:4,
  var2_t1 = 5:6,
  var2_t2 = 7:8
)

dat |>
  pivot_longer(starts_with("var"),
    names_to = c(".value", "timepoint"),
    names_sep = "_"
  )
#> # A tibble: 4 × 6
#>   SubjectID Gender   Age timepoint  var1  var2
#>       <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <chr>     <int> <int>
#> 1         1 M         20 t1            1     5
#> 2         1 M         20 t2            3     7
#> 3         2 F         30 t1            2     6
#> 4         2 F         30 t2            4     8
```

Comment: thanks  a lot. I had  to do a  slight  modification and input a an array of variable names  into the "starts_with()"function, as  my variables didn't have a common name.

Answer (score 0):

I had to input a vector of strings since my variables mostly didn't share a common name, therefore making it useless to use `starts_with("var")`. After needing to unlabel the dataframe using the package "labelled", since it was an SPSS imported dataset,

```
df<-as.data.frame(unlabelled(df))
varNames<-names(df)
```

This worked:

```
df_long<-df %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with(varNames),
                            names_to = c(".value", "timepoint"),
                            names_sep = "_"
  )
```